# Select columns from multiple rda files R and save the selected output

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I would like to select (by names or position) specified columns in multiple .rda files stored in a directory and then save them only with the selected columns (preferably using purrr and dplyr). 
The .rda files have all the same structure: 38 columns, first 28 columns have the same names, the last 10 columns have different names with the same prefix ("SC*").

This is what I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
file_names <- as.list(dir(path=".", pattern="ASJC*"))
```

I load the files selected

```
files <- map(file_names,load,environment())
```

Then I try to select specified columns by names:

```
 files_selected <- map(files,dplyr::select(SOURCERECORD_ID,starts_with("SC*")))
```

and I got the following error message:

> Error in dplyr::select(SOURCERECORD_ID, starts_with("SC*")) : 
>             object 'SOURCERECORD_ID' not found

So i tried the following code:

```
files_selected <- map(files,dplyr::select(1,29:38)
```

with another error message:

> Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
>         no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

This is the structure of .rda files:

```
df1 <- structure(list(SOURCERECORD_ID = c("18659", "13951", "5400152705", 
                                   "16500154707", "20300195074", "19472"), TITOLO_FONTE = c("ANAIS DA ACADEMIA BRASILEIRA DE CIENCIAS", 
                                                                                            "ARABIAN JOURNAL FOR SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING", "ARCHIVES DES SCIENCES", 
                                                                                            "ASIAN JOURNAL OF SCIENTIFIC RESEARCH", "ASM SCIENCE JOURNAL", 
                                                                                            "BEIJING DAXUE XUEBAO (ZIRAN KEXUE BAN)/ACTA SCIENTIARUM NATURALIUM UNIVERSITATIS PEKINENSIS"
                                   ), ISSN_P = c("0001-3765", "1319-8025", "1661-464X", "1992-1454", 
                                                 "1823-6782", "0479-8023"), ISSN_E = c("1678-2690", NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA), STATUS = c("Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
                                                                                                           "Active"), COPERTURA = c("1994-ongoing, 1970-1992, 1949", "2003-ongoing, 1981", 
                                                                                                                                    "2017-ongoing, 2004-2014", "2009-ongoing", "2011-ongoing", "2001-ongoing"
                                                                                                           ), LINGUA = c("ENG", "ENG", "ENG, FRE", "ENG", "ENG", "CHI"), 
               CS2014 = c(0.95, 1.19, 0.64, 0.55, 0.1, 0.24), CS2015 = c(0.89, 
                                                                         0.81, 0.57, 0.36, 0.06, 0.17), CS2016 = c(1.05, 1.02, NA, 
                                                                                                                   0.64, 0.11, 0.35), SJR2014 = c(0.42, 0.332, 0.285, 0.394, 
                                                                                                                                                  0.107, 0.13), SJR2015 = c(0.332, 0.335, 0.201, 0.163, 0.122, 
                                                                                                                                                                            0.123), SJR2016 = c(0.386, 0.29, 0.149, 0.195, 0.101, 0.157
                                                                                                                                                                            ), SNIP2014 = c(0.756, 1.149, 0.236, 1.021, 0.408, 0.338), 
               SNIP2015 = c(0.67, 0.51, 0.362, 0.472, 0.082, 0.164), SNIP2016 = c(0.713, 
                                                                                  0.657, 0.275, 0.549, 0.595, 0.265), TIPO_FONTE = c("Journal", 
                                                                                                                                     "Journal", "Journal", "Journal", "Journal", "Journal"), STORIA_TITOLO = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               NA, "Formerly known as", NA, NA, NA), TITOLI_COLLEGATI = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          NA, "Archives des Sciences et Compte Rendu Seances de la Societe", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          NA, NA, NA), EDITORE = c("Academia Brasileira de Ciencias", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Springer Verlag", "Societe de physique et d'histoire naturelle", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Asian Network for Scientific Information", "Akademi Sains Malaysia", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Beijing University Press"), PAESE_EDITORE = c("Brazil", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "Germany", "Switzerland", "Pakistan", "Malaysia", "China"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), ASJC = c("1000;", "1000;", "1000;", "1000;", "1000;", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "1000;"), AVG_CS = c(0.963, 1.007, 0.605, 0.517, 0.09, 0.253
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), AVG_SJR = c(0.379, 0.319, 0.212, 0.251, 0.11, 0.137), 
               AVG_SNIP = c(0.713, 0.772, 0.291, 0.681, 0.362, 0.256), ELEGGIBILE = c("Eleggibile", 
                                                                                      "Eleggibile", "Eleggibile", "Eleggibile", "Eleggibile", "Eleggibile"
               ), Percentili_SJR = c(15L, 21L, 47L, 35L, 89L, 77L), Percentili_SNIP = c(25L, 
                                                                                        19L, 74L, 28L, 61L, 78L), SC13A_1000_SJR = c("Bottom", "Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                     "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13B_1000_SJR = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13C_1000_SJR = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13D_1000_SJR = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13D4_1000_SJR = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13A_1000_SNIP = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13B_1000_SNIP = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13C_1000_SNIP = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13D_1000_SNIP = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom"), SC13D4_1000_SNIP = c("Bottom", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Bottom")), .Names = c("SOURCERECORD_ID", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "TITOLO_FONTE", "ISSN_P", "ISSN_E", "STATUS", "COPERTURA", "LINGUA", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "CS2014", "CS2015", "CS2016", "SJR2014", "SJR2015", "SJR2016", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "SNIP2014", "SNIP2015", "SNIP2016", "TIPO_FONTE", "STORIA_TITOLO", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "TITOLI_COLLEGATI", "EDITORE", "PAESE_EDITORE", "ASJC", "AVG_CS", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "AVG_SJR", "AVG_SNIP", "ELEGGIBILE", "Percentili_SJR", "Percentili_SNIP", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "SC13A_1000_SJR", "SC13B_1000_SJR", "SC13C_1000_SJR", "SC13D_1000_SJR", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "SC13D4_1000_SJR", "SC13A_1000_SNIP", "SC13B_1000_SNIP", "SC13C_1000_SNIP", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "SC13D_1000_SNIP", "SC13D4_1000_SNIP"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `files <- map(file_names,load,environment())` holds a list of datframes?

If yes, then try this

```
map(files,~ dplyr::select(.,SOURCERECORD_ID,starts_with("SC*")))
```

I think what's missing is the `~` before the `select` function, and the `.` in the select function since `select` is `select(.data, ...`)`. By`.` you imply here is where the each dataset goes